# Best way to block other threads until one is finished

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have many threads which monitor a certain state. If the application gets into that state, then I need to do some extra work. I want to allow just 1 thread to execute that and want to block the others until that work is finished. Blocking mean, that they must not execute that task again.

I have the following scenario:

```
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock

    void doSomething() {

      if (lock.tryLock()) {

       try {
         doSomeWork()
       } finally {
         lock.unLock()
       }
      } else {
        // wait for DoSomeWork is done
      }
    }
```

I can monitor `lock.isLocked()` in a loop, but actually I just want to have some sort of wait until the work is finished by the other thread.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You can use `lock.lock()` which will wait for the lock to be released and guaratees that only one thread has it at a given time, isn't that what you want?

Comment: ah yes, somehow I just overcomplicated it. having `try {lock.lock() } finally {lock.unlock()}` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation about [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class:

> It is recommended practice to always immediately follow a call to
>   lock with a try block, most typically in a before/after construction
>   such as:

```
class X {
   private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   // ...

   public void m() {
     lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
     try {
       // ... method body
     } finally {
       lock.unlock()
     }
   }
 }
```

From the documentation for [lock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock--) method:*"If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired"* and this is what you want to be guaranteed in your scenario.